# Undefined DateTimepicker Value -NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js

I have a code that add new events created by the customer to the database, everything was working well until I added the image Upload fearture

What I did exactly is this :

1- I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form like below

```
<form class="form-group label-floating is-select" action="/envoi/event" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2- inside that form I got this input `<input name="datetimepicker" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datetimepicker"`

3- in server side Node I got this

```
const dateNew = moment(req.body.datetimepicker, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    console.log(req.body.datetimepicker)
    console.log(dateNew)
```

The output of both `console.log` are below

```
undefined
Moment<Invalid date>
```

both `datetimepicker and enctype="multipart/form-data"` are like this

```
<form class="form-group label-floating is-select" action="/envoi/event" 
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group date-time-picker label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Event Date</label>
    <input name="datetimepicker" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datetimepicker">
    </div>
    </form>
```

What I noticed that If I delete this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` everything works perfectly and I get as result the right value

Anyone faced this kind of problems ? or maybe I did something wrong

Best Regards,

Comment: will it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

Comment: @falinsky when I used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the value date is now correct but the  image upload is not working and if I replace it to `multipart/form-data`  => the inverse is happening  upload is working but date is undefined

Comment: @falinsky I made some modification and it is working , could it possible to post your comment as answer ? to accept and vote u ?

Comment: it would be better if you create a detailed answer on your own question with what you did. You will be able to accept it later. This way this question and answer will have more value for the community.